# append more items to listfragment on scroll end

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment, onscrolllistener

i know there are a lot of examples for this question on stackoverflow , but i don't know how to implement any of them on my code .

what i want to do is to load data from json url (first 15 element) , and append them to listfragment and when the user scroll down to the end of the list another 15 elements appended (total 30 elements on the list) and so on..

now i can fetch the first 15 elements correctly , but when i try to add more items when the user reach end of scroll i don't know what to do ... here is my code:

in **MainActivity** i have the following class which extend listfragment :

```
  public static class NewsFragment extends ListFragment implements ILoadDataListener, OnScrollListener {

         private ListView listView; 
         private NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
         private  int currentPage=1;
         @Override
         public  View  onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceStatee){

             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news, container, false);
             listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
             return rootView;
         }

         @Override
          public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            getListView().setOnScrollListener( this);
            // URL to the JSON data         
            String strUrl = "http://opetmar.hostzi.com/test.php";
         // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data 
            ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progress.setMessage("loading ...");
            GetJSON downloadTask = new GetJSON(this , progress , "news");

            // Starting the download process
            downloadTask.execute(strUrl);       


          }


         @Override
            public void onComplete(String[] titles  , String[] images , String[] ids , String[] snippets , String[] data) {
            if ( currentPage == 1 ){
                newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter( getActivity() , titles , images , ids , snippets , data );
                listView.setAdapter(newsAdapter); 
            }else {

            }
            }

         @Override
            public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

                super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
                DataHolder holder;
                holder  = (DataHolder) v.getTag();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewsOpen.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("image", holder.image);
                myIntent.putExtra("data", holder.data); 
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }

         @Override
         public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                 int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView, int scrollState) {
             if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= listView.getCount() - 1 ) {
                        currentPage++;  
                        String strUrl = "http://opetmar.hostzi.com/test.php?page="+currentPage;
                            ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                            progress.setMessage("loading ...");
                            GetJSON downloadTask = new GetJSON(this , progress , "news");

                            // Starting the download process
                            downloadTask.execute(strUrl);       
                    }
                }


         }
    }
```

**NewsAdapter.java**

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context;
private final String[] titles;
private final String[] images;
private final String[] ids;
private final String[] snippets;
private final String[] data;
public NewsAdapter(Context context, String[] titles, String[] images , String[] ids , String[] snippets , String[] data) {
    super(context, R.layout.drawer_list_item, titles);
    this.context = context;
    this.titles = titles;
    this.images = images;
    this.ids = ids;
    this.snippets = snippets;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_item, parent, false);
    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
    TextView snippet = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.news_snippet);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.news_thumble);
    title.setText(titles[position]);
    snippet.setText(snippets[position]);
    DataHolder holder = new DataHolder();
    holder.data=data[position];
    holder.image=images[position];
    rowView.setTag(holder);
    new DownloadImageTask(imageView).execute(images[position]);

    return rowView;
}


   public class DataHolder {
   String image;
   String data;

 }

   }
```

**GetJSON.java**

```
   /** AsyncTask to download json data */
    public class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    String data = null;
    private ListView listView;  
 private NewsAdapter newsAdapter;
 private ILoadDataListener mListener;
private ProgressDialog progress;
private String type;

   public GetJSON(ILoadDataListener listener ,  ProgressDialog progress , String type) {
       this.mListener = listener;
       this.progress = progress;
       this.type = type;
   }
   public void onPreExecute() {
        progress.show();
      }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                try{
                    data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                }
                return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null){
         if (this.type == "news") {
            try {
                JSONObject jObject;
                jObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jCountries = jObject.optJSONArray("news");
                ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> stringArrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> stringArrayList3 = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> stringArrayList4 = new ArrayList<String>();
                ArrayList<String> stringArrayList5 = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i=0; i < jCountries.length(); i++)
                {
                    try {
                        JSONObject oneObject = jCountries.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Pulling items from the array
                        stringArrayList.add(oneObject.getString("title"));
                        stringArrayList2.add( oneObject.getString("image"));
                        stringArrayList3.add( oneObject.getString("id"));
                        stringArrayList4.add( oneObject.getString("snippet"));
                        stringArrayList5.add( oneObject.getString("data"));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // Oops
                    }
                }
                String [] stringArray = stringArrayList.toArray(new String[stringArrayList.size()]);
                String [] stringArray2 = stringArrayList2.toArray(new String[stringArrayList2.size()]);
                String [] stringArray3 = stringArrayList3.toArray(new String[stringArrayList3.size()]);
                String [] stringArray4 = stringArrayList4.toArray(new String[stringArrayList4.size()]);
                String [] stringArray5 = stringArrayList5.toArray(new String[stringArrayList5.size()]);
                progress.dismiss();
                 if (mListener != null) {  
                       mListener.onComplete(stringArray , stringArray2 , stringArray3 , stringArray4 , stringArray5);
                   }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }
            }else{
              Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
         }
        }

        /** A method to download json data from url */
        private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
            String data = "";
            InputStream iStream = null;
            try{
                    URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                    // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    // Connecting to url 
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    // Reading data from url 
                    iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                    StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                    String line = "";
                    while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                    }

                    data = sb.toString();

                    br.close();

            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
            }finally{
                    iStream.close();
            }
            return data;

        }

   }
```

to be more specific , when the user reach the end of the scroll the following code will triggered which load more data from json url:

```
     @Override
         public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView, int scrollState) {
             if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= listView.getCount() - 1 ) {
                        currentPage++;  
                        String strUrl = "http://opetmar.hostzi.com/test.php?page="+currentPage;
                            ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                            progress.setMessage("loading ...");
                            GetJSON downloadTask = new GetJSON(this , progress , "news");

                            // Starting the download process
                            downloadTask.execute(strUrl);       
                    }
                }
```

then the GetJSON will call the following method after finish fetching and parsing data :

```
 @Override
            public void onComplete(String[] titles  , String[] images , String[] ids , String[] snippets , String[] data) {
            if ( currentPage == 1 ){
                newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter( getActivity() , titles , images , ids , snippets , data );
                listView.setAdapter(newsAdapter); 
            }else {

            }
            }
```

so if **currentpage** is not equal one , i want to append more data . how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it's possible for ListView, but using Gallery you can override

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY);

and use it to define the events when the items scrolled to the end. I did so to organize infinite list of calendar ietms in the gallery.

Regards,

Alex.